# How can I do this regex on C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string, that can have some html tags. I'd like to remove some of them (with the data on it), but not all tags.

In fact I'd like to remove `<img />` and `<div>...</div>`.

So for example, if I have the string `hello <div>bye bye</div> marco` Id like to get `hello marco`.

How can I do this on C#?

Comment: Be aware that Regular Expressions won't be able to correctly handle divs inside other divs, so they're not ideal for this scenario

Comment: I know. Any other ideas?

Comment: @William: He is using C#. The .NET regex implementation can handle nested divs (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx). But you really really do not want to do this. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use regex for XML. Depending on the language you should use some XML library.

In this case the regex is pretty simple, though:

```
        string s = "hello <div>bye bye</div> marco <img />";

        Regex rgx = new Regex("(<div>[^<]*</div>)|(<img */>)");
        s = rgx.Replace(s, "");
```

Comment: Please do not encourage this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @fiver, No, it solves his problem. Even though solving the problem like this is a bad idea.

Comment: Won't work if there's divs inside other divs, which is why Regexes aren't a good idea for this sort of thing

Comment: True! Well, in case of nested divs it won't break the XML - it will remove the innermost div only. But I totally agree. Regex + XML = Disaster

Comment: @Filip Ekberg : I don't know any way to solve this problem, do you? P.S. Why do you talk about XML? I'm doing it on HTML :)

Comment: I think you should use `.*?` instead of `[^<]*` to include constructs like "<div><b>...</b></div?" and change `img */>` to `img [^>]*>` to account for attributes.

Comment: Tried your solution, but with this string `Hello<div id=\"attachment_2949\"> my name is <img class=\"size-medium wp-image-2949\" src=\"link.jpg\" /> Eric</div> Marco`, for example, nothing change :(

Comment: The proposed solution will eat everything from the first div through the last /div.  Might want to make the `*` lazy like this: `*?`

Comment: @fiver : please try replacing this `string s = "Hello<div id=\"attachment_2949\"> my name is <img class=\"size-medium wp-image-2949\" src=\"link.jpg\" /> Eric</div> Marco";` : it wont works. Also if I change regex from `(<div>[^<]` to `(<div[^<]`

Answer (score 7):

I think you are aware about people's general opinion about [parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). I would recommend you using a HTML parser such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Here's a sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml("hello <div>bye bye</div> marco <img src=\"http://example.com\"/> test");

        for (int i = 0; i < doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            var child = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[i];
            if (child.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element && new[] { "div", "img" }.Contains(child.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                doc.DocumentNode.RemoveChild(child);
            }
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb); // prints "hello  marco  test"
     }

}
```

Comment: Haha "parsing HTML with regex" is the best post EVER. :)

Comment: @markzzz: You're going to need to actually parse it *sometime*, and once you've learned your way around such a library, it's generally actually *easier* than writing a regex since you can use tools that talk on the level you're thinking (e.g. XPath for elements) rather than mind-bending token-twisting.  Learn it once, and be done with it.